# Using Newton's method, find the root of $x^3+2x-1$ with an accuracy of $5$ decimal places

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

> Using Newton's method, find the root of $x^3+2x-1$ with an accuracy of $5$ decimal places.

I think the solution is $0.45339$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Does $x^3+2x-1$ have different signs for $x=0.453385$ and $x=0.453395$? If so, that's s root with 5 digits accuracy.

But actually, according to my calculator we have

$$\begin{array}{c|c} x & x^3+2x-1 \\ \hline
0.453385 & \approx -3\times 10^{-5} \\
0.453395 & \approx -7\times 10^{-6} \\
0.453400 & \approx +6\times 10^{-6} \end{array} $$
so the root is between $0.453395$ and $0.453400$, and should therefore be given with 5 significant digits as $0.45340$.

---

Since the exercise specifically asks you to *use Newton's method*, however, most of what you will be judged on is probably setting up the right expression to iterate, showing your successive approximations, and demonstrating when to stop iterating.

Comment: You have a typo at the top of your little table, I think.

Comment: @Ian: Fixed now.

Comment: I think the $0.453395$ should be $0.453397$

Comment: @E.H.E: The reason to evaluate at $0.453395$ is that it is boundary between points that round to $0.45339$ and points that round to $0.45340$.

Comment: I mean that  the value in your table

Comment: @E.H.E: And I'm explaining why $0.453395$ is the value I want to have in my table.

Comment: i think that the final solution is $0.45339$ cuz we stop at the first five decimal places.why we round it

Comment: @MantolInis: The real root is $0.4533976515\ldots$, which is closer to $0.45340$ than it is to $0.45339$. Therefore $0.45340$ is the 5-decimal number that is closest to the real root, and is therefore how that number would usually be represented with to 5 decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x^3+2x-1$ is an increasing function over $\mathbb{R}$, since $f'(x)=3x^2+2$ is always positive.
In a similar way we have that $f(x)$ is convex over $\mathbb{R}^+$. Newton's 
iteration
$$ x\to x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} $$
in our case takes the form
$$ x\to \frac{1+2 x^3}{2+3 x^2} $$
and since $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)>0$, Newton's iteration with starting point $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ gives a decreasing sequence that converges quadratically to the only real zero of $f(x)$. Such a sequence is
$$ \frac{1}{2},\quad\frac{5}{11},\quad \frac{1581}{3487},\quad \frac{50302634185}{110945952227} $$
where the last two ratios share the $\color{red}{0.45339}$ part of their decimal representation.

Answer (score 0):

> - $\displaystyle{\mathrm{f}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\,,\quad\mathrm{f}\left(\,x\,\right) = x^{3} + 2x - 1}$. Since $\,\mathrm{f}$ is a continuous function in $\displaystyle{\left[\,0,1\,\right]}$
>     and
>     $\displaystyle{\,\mathrm{f}\left(\,0\,\right)
>   \,\mathrm{f}\left(\,1\,\right) < 0}$; there is, at least, a root $r$ $\displaystyle{\in \left(\,0,1\,\right)}$.
> - As a 'blind guess' we choose
>     $\displaystyle{g = 0.5 = {0 + 1 \over 2}}$ as our 'starting point'which sets $\displaystyle{\left\vert\,g -r\,\right\vert < 0.25}$.
> - With a 'little' $\texttt{C++}$ program ( see below ), I'll get:

```
      Root = 0.4533976515
Iterations = 4
       TOL = 1.564621925e-08
```

```
// newtonRapson0.cc  30-ag-16  Felix Marin
/*
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908292/using-newtons-method-find-the-root-of-x32x-1-with-an-accuracy-of-5-decim/1908842#190884
*/
#include <cfloat>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const double TOL = 1.05*sqrt(DBL_EPSILON);
const double MAXITER = 50U;

inline double dx(double x)
{
 return -(x*(x*x + 2.0) - 1.0)/(3.0*x*x + 2.0);
}

int main()
{
 double d,tol,xAnt,x = 0.5;
 size_t n = 0;

 while (n++ < MAXITER) {
       xAnt = x;
       d = dx(x);
       x += d;
       tol = abs(xAnt + d/2.0);
       tol = (tol > 0) ? (abs(d)/tol):abs(d);
       if (tol <= TOL ) break;
 }

 cout<<setprecision(10)<<"      Root = "<<x<<endl;
 cout<<"Iterations = "<<n<<endl;
 cout<<"       TOL = "<<TOL<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```